# ERROR kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "MenuScreen"

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I created this kivymd app and when the user enters the <tabelaPacientes> screen, I would like to put a button for them to come back to the <MenuScreen>. When I click this button I get an error:
`kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "MenuScreen"`

Code below:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

import json
import requests

link=[]


class MenuScreen(MDScreen):
    def btn_cadastro(self):
        cadastro_usuario(self.ids.text_cpf.text,self.ids.text_nome.text)


class TabelaPacientes(MDScreen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        for i in range(len(get_usuario())):
            nome=get_usuario()[i][1]
            self.ids.lista.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"{nome}"))


class PerfilPaciente(MDScreen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(TabelaPacientes(name='TabelaPacientes'))
sm.add_widget(PerfilPaciente(name='PerfilPaciente'))


def cadastro_usuario(cpf, nome):
    cadastro = {'cpf': cpf, 'nome': nome}
    requisicao = requests.patch(f'{link}/pacientes/{cpf}/.json', data=json.dumps(cadastro))
    return True

def get_usuario():
    lst=[]
    requisicao = requests.get(f'{link}/pacientes/.json')
    dicionario = requisicao.json()
    for key in dicionario:
        cpfbd=dicionario[key]['cpf']
        nomedb=dicionario[key]['nome']
        pacientes=(cpfbd,nomedb)
        lst.append(pacientes)
    return lst

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette="Blue"
        screen = Builder.load_file("tela.kv")
        return screen


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

tela.kv :

```
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    TabelaPacientes:
    PerfilPaciente:

<MenuScreen>:
    nome:'menu'
    MDLabel:
        text: "Seja Bem-vindo! Cadastre um novo paciente:"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .70}
        halign: "center"
        bold: True
        font_style: "Caption"
    MDTextField:
        hint_text:"Nome"
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        id: text_nome
    MDTextField:
        hint_text:"CPF"
        helper_text:'texto de apoio'
        max_text_length:11
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        id: text_cpf

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"cadastrar"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.3}
        on_release:root.btn_cadastro()

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"Tabela de Pacientes"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.2}
        on_press:root.manager.current='TabelaPacientes'
        
<TabelaPacientes>:
    name:'TabelaPacientes'
    MDScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: lista
            OneLineListItem:
                text:'test'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Go back'
        on_press:root.manager.current='MenuScreen'
            

<PerfilPaciente>:
    nome:'PerfilPaciente'    
    MDLabel:
        id: nome_paciente
        text:'O nome do paciente aparecerá aqui'
```

I don't know how to fix this. I did the same thing for the user to go from <menuScreen> to <tabelaPacientes> and it works, but the other way around doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you put the name='menu'

```
 sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
```

For this you must put:

```
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    text:'Go back'
    on_press:root.manager.current='menu'
```